# `update` function doesn't work correctly for bokeh interactors in python

Tags: python, bokeh, interactors

I have a source code that plots the alphashape of a stock price. There's a slider to update the plot dynamically. But the `update function` doesn't work as expected.

Here's the source code.

```
x=[76.84,76.85,76.86,76.87,76.88,76.9,76.91,76.92,76.93,76.94,76.97,76.97,76.98,76.99,77.0,77.03,77.03,77.04,77.05,77.06,77.09,77.09,77.1,77.11,77.12,77.15,77.16,77.16,77.17,77.18,77.21,77.22,77.22,77.23,77.24,77.27,77.28,77.28,77.29,77.3,77.33,77.34,77.35,77.35,77.36,77.39,77.4,77.41,77.41,77.42,77.45,77.46,77.47,77.47,77.48,77.51,77.52,77.53,77.54,77.54,77.57,77.58,77.59,77.6,77.6,77.63,77.64,77.65,77.66,77.66,77.69,77.7,77.71,77.72,77.73,77.75,77.76,77.77,77.78,77.79,77.81,77.82,77.83,77.84,77.85,77.87,77.88,77.89,77.9,77.91,77.93,77.94,77.95,77.96,77.97,77.99,78.0,78.01,78.02,78.03,78.05,78.06,78.07,78.08,78.09,78.13,78.14,78.15,78.17,78.18,78.19,78.2,78.21,78.24,78.24,78.25,78.26,78.27,78.3,78.3,78.31,78.32,78.33,78.36,78.36,78.37,78.38,78.39,78.42,78.43,78.43,78.44,78.45,78.48,78.49,78.49,78.5,78.51,78.54,78.55,78.55,78.56,78.57,78.6,78.61,78.62,78.62,78.63,78.66,78.67,78.68,78.68,78.69,78.72,78.73,78.74,78.74,78.75,78.78,78.79,78.8,78.81,78.81,78.84,78.85,78.86,78.87,78.87,78.91,78.92,78.93,78.94,78.96,78.97,78.98,78.99,79.0,79.02,79.03,79.04,79.05,79.06,79.08,79.09,79.1,79.11,79.12,79.2,79.21,79.22,79.23,79.24,79.26,79.27,79.28,79.29,79.3,79.32,79.33,79.34,79.35,79.36,79.38,79.39,79.4,79.41,79.42,79.44,79.45,79.46,79.47,79.48,79.51,79.51,79.52,79.53,79.54,79.57,79.57,79.58,79.59,79.6,79.63,79.63,79.64,79.65,79.66,79.69,79.7,79.7,79.71,79.72,79.75,79.76,79.76,79.77,79.78,79.81,79.82,79.82,79.83,79.84,79.87,79.88,79.89,79.89,79.9,79.94,79.95,79.95,79.96,79.99,80.0,80.01,80.02,80.02,80.05,80.06,80.07,80.08,80.08,80.11,80.12,80.13,80.14,80.14,80.17,80.18,80.19,80.2,80.21,80.23,80.24,80.25,80.26,80.27,80.29,80.3,80.31,80.32,80.33,80.35,80.36,80.37,80.38,80.39,80.41,80.42,80.43,80.44,80.45,80.47,80.48,80.49,80.5,80.51,80.53,80.54,80.55,80.56,80.57,80.59,80.6,80.61,80.62,80.63,80.65,80.66,80.67,80.68,80.69,80.71,80.72,80.73,80.74,80.75,80.78,80.78,80.79,80.8,80.81,80.84,80.84,80.85,80.86,80.87,80.9,80.9,80.91,80.92,80.93,80.96,80.97,80.97,80.98,80.99,81.02,81.03,81.03,81.04,81.05,81.08,81.09,81.1,81.1,81.11,81.14,81.15,81.16,81.16,81.17,81.2,81.21,81.22,81.22,81.23,81.28,81.29,81.29,81.32,81.33,81.34,81.35,81.35,81.38,81.39,81.4,81.41,81.41,81.44,81.45,81.46,81.47,81.48,81.5,81.51,81.52,81.53,81.54,81.56,81.57,81.58,81.59,81.6,81.62,81.63,81.64,81.65,81.66,81.68,81.69,81.7,81.71,81.72,81.74,81.75,81.76,81.77,81.78,81.8,81.81,81.82,81.83,81.84,81.86,81.87,81.88,81.89,81.9,81.92,81.93,81.94,81.95,81.96,81.98,81.99,82.0,82.01,82.02,82.05,82.06,82.07,82.08,82.11,82.11,82.12,82.13,82.14,82.17,82.18,82.18,82.19,82.2,82.23,82.24,82.24,82.25,82.26,82.29,82.3,82.3,82.31,82.32,82.35,82.36,82.37,82.37,82.38,82.41,82.42,82.43,82.43,82.44,82.59,82.6,82.61,82.62,82.62,82.65,82.66,82.67,82.68,82.68,82.71,82.72,82.73,82.74,82.75,82.77,82.78,82.79,82.8,82.81,82.83,82.84,82.85,82.86,82.87,82.89,82.9,82.91,82.92,82.93,82.95,82.96,82.97,82.98,82.99,83.01,83.02,83.03,83.04,83.05,83.07,83.08,83.1,83.11,83.13,83.14,83.15,83.16,83.17,83.19,83.2,83.21,83.22,83.23,83.26,83.26,83.27,83.28,83.29,83.32,83.32,83.33,83.34,83.35,83.38,83.38,83.39,83.4,83.41,83.44,83.45,83.45,83.46,83.47,83.5,83.51,83.51,83.52,83.53,83.56,83.57,83.57,83.58,83.59,83.62,83.63,83.64,83.64,83.65,83.68,83.69,83.7,83.7,83.71,83.74,83.75,83.76,83.76,83.77,83.8,83.81,83.82,83.83,83.83,83.86,83.87,83.88,83.89,83.89,83.92,83.93,83.94,83.95,83.95,83.98,83.99,84.0,84.01,84.02,84.04,84.05,84.06,84.07,84.08,84.1,84.11,84.12,84.13,84.14,84.16,84.17,84.18,84.19,84.2,84.22,84.23,84.24,84.25,84.26,84.28,84.29,84.3,84.31,84.32,84.34,84.35,84.36,84.37,84.38,84.43,84.44,84.46,84.47,84.48,84.49,84.5,84.53,84.53,84.54,84.55,84.56,84.59,84.59,84.6,84.61,84.62,84.65,84.65,84.66,84.67,84.68,84.71,84.72,84.72,84.73,84.74,84.77,84.78,84.78,84.79,84.8,84.83,84.84,84.84,84.85,84.86,84.89,84.9,84.91,84.91,84.92,84.95,84.96,84.97,84.97,84.98,85.01,85.02,85.03,85.03,85.04,85.07,85.08,85.09,85.1,85.1,85.13,85.14,85.15,85.16,85.16,85.19,85.2,85.22,85.22,85.25,85.26,85.27,85.28,85.29,85.31,85.32,85.33,85.34,85.35,85.37,85.38,85.39,85.4,85.41,85.43,85.44,85.45,85.46,85.47,85.61,85.62,85.63,85.64,85.65,85.67,85.68,85.69,85.7,85.71,85.73,85.74,85.75,85.76,85.77,85.8,85.8,85.81,85.82,85.83,85.86,85.86,85.87,85.88,85.89,85.92,85.92,85.93,85.94,85.95,85.98,85.99,85.99,86.0,86.01,86.04,86.05,86.05,86.06,86.07,86.1,86.11,86.11,86.12,86.13,86.16,86.17,86.18,86.18,86.19,86.22,86.23,86.24,86.28,86.29,86.3,86.3,86.31,86.34,86.35,86.36,86.37,86.37,86.4,86.41,86.42,86.43,86.43,86.46,86.47,86.48,86.49,86.5,86.52,86.53,86.54,86.55,86.56,86.58,86.59,86.6,86.61,86.62,86.64,86.65,86.66,86.67,86.68,86.7,86.71,86.72,86.73,86.74,86.78,86.79,86.8,86.82,86.83,86.84,86.85,86.86,86.88,86.89,86.9,86.91,86.92,86.94,86.95,86.96,86.97,86.98,87.0,87.01,87.02,87.03,87.04,87.07,87.07,87.08,87.09,87.1,87.13,87.13,87.14,87.15,87.16,87.19,87.19,87.2,87.21,87.22,87.25,87.26,87.26,87.27,87.28,87.31,87.32,87.32,87.33,87.34,87.37,87.38,87.38,87.39,87.4,87.43,87.44,87.45,87.45,87.46,87.49,87.5,87.51,87.51,87.52,87.55,87.56,87.61,87.62,87.63,87.64,87.64,87.67,87.68,87.69,87.7,87.7,87.73,87.74,87.75,87.76,87.77,87.79,87.8,87.81,87.82,87.83,87.85,87.86,87.87,87.88,87.89,87.91,87.92,87.93,87.94,87.95,87.97,87.98,87.99,88.0,88.01,88.03,88.04,88.05,88.06,88.07,88.09,88.1,88.11,88.12,88.13,88.15,88.16,88.17,88.18,88.19,88.21,88.22,88.23,88.24,88.25,88.27,88.28,88.29,88.3,88.31,88.34,88.34,88.35,88.4,88.4,88.41,88.42,88.43,88.46,88.46,88.47,88.48,88.49,88.52,88.53,88.53,88.54,88.55,88.7,88.71,88.72,88.72,88.73,88.76,88.77,88.78,88.78,88.79,88.82,88.83,88.84,88.85,88.85,88.88,88.89,88.9,88.91,88.91,88.94,88.95,88.96,88.97,88.97,89.0,89.01,89.02,89.03,89.04,89.06,89.07,89.08,89.09,89.1,89.12,89.13,89.14,89.15,89.16,89.18,89.19,89.2,89.21,89.22,89.24,89.25,89.26,89.27,89.28,89.3,89.31,89.32,89.33,89.34,89.36,89.37,89.38,89.39,89.42,89.43,89.44,89.45,89.46,89.48,89.49,89.5,89.51,89.52,89.54,89.55,89.56,89.57,89.58,89.61]

y=[2.29,2.41,2.4,2.38,2.43,2.42,2.38,2.36,2.4,2.37,2.36,2.37,2.34,2.32,2.31,2.25,2.25,2.21,2.2,2.21,2.21,2.21,2.21,2.19,2.17,2.1,2.08,2.08,2.12,2.15,2.1,2.09,2.1,2.08,2.08,2.01,2.0,1.98,1.98,1.95,1.92,1.92,1.92,1.92,1.92,1.88,1.88,1.91,1.91,1.88,1.89,1.87,1.85,1.84,1.83,1.88,1.93,1.88,1.82,1.82,2.08,2.13,2.35,2.32,2.37,2.34,2.25,2.35,2.33,2.34,2.32,2.34,2.39,2.53,2.49,2.53,2.54,2.55,2.53,2.52,2.52,2.54,2.66,2.71,2.81,2.92,3.09,2.99,3.03,2.98,3.01,2.98,2.93,2.91,2.93,2.91,2.89,2.92,2.9,2.87,2.9,2.9,2.93,2.83,2.78,2.67,2.6,2.66,2.61,2.61,2.61,2.54,2.56,2.51,2.52,2.55,2.6,2.6,2.67,2.63,2.62,2.63,2.61,2.58,2.59,2.59,2.62,2.59,2.58,2.61,2.63,2.6,2.63,2.63,2.61,2.6,2.58,2.58,2.57,2.58,2.58,2.58,2.58,2.57,2.58,2.58,2.58,2.58,2.55,2.52,2.53,2.53,2.51,2.46,2.48,2.45,2.54,2.53,2.49,2.51,2.49,2.48,2.49,2.47,2.48,2.49,2.48,2.5,2.5,2.55,2.53,2.52,2.51,2.49,2.5,2.49,2.49,2.47,2.46,2.48,2.45,2.45,2.43,2.43,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.45,2.46,2.45,2.44,2.44,2.45,2.45,2.47,2.56,2.52,2.48,2.47,2.5,2.54,2.54,2.58,2.61,2.63,2.63,2.63,2.61,2.59,2.59,2.56,2.57,2.58,2.56,2.57,2.61,2.59,2.6,2.6,2.58,2.6,2.59,2.6,2.61,2.61,2.59,2.6,2.62,2.62,2.6,2.61,2.59,2.59,2.59,2.59,2.61,2.67,2.65,2.63,2.63,2.6,2.56,2.59,2.59,2.59,2.58,2.58,2.57,2.58,2.55,2.55,2.58,2.58,2.57,2.58,2.83,2.88,2.93,2.79,2.82,2.81,2.86,2.86,2.85,2.82,2.82,2.82,2.78,2.78,2.82,2.79,2.8,2.79,2.79,2.78,2.72,2.73,2.71,2.72,2.73,2.73,2.74,2.74,2.72,2.73,2.73,2.71,2.68,2.71,2.75,2.84,2.91,2.89,2.92,2.97,2.96,2.94,2.99,3.04,2.97,2.99,2.97,2.99,2.98,2.99,3.0,3.01,2.99,2.98,2.99,2.99,2.99,3.01,2.96,2.97,3.0,2.98,2.97,2.96,2.96,3.0,3.0,2.99,2.98,2.99,2.99,2.99,2.99,2.99,2.99,2.98,2.98,2.98,2.98,3.02,3.03,3.03,3.05,3.09,3.08,3.1,3.12,3.14,3.13,3.12,3.14,3.15,3.13,3.15,3.14,3.14,3.14,3.14,3.13,3.11,3.08,3.08,3.08,3.08,3.1,3.11,3.11,3.11,3.09,3.13,3.17,3.28,3.43,3.52,3.47,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.44,3.46,3.46,3.45,3.44,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.47,3.5,3.54,3.52,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.44,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.43,3.45,3.48,3.48,3.45,3.46,3.43,3.46,3.45,3.43,3.43,3.42,3.42,3.43,3.42,3.41,3.39,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.4,3.39,3.38,3.39,3.37,3.37,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.37,3.36,3.37,3.36,3.36,3.37,3.36,3.41,3.41,3.4,3.39,3.39,3.37,3.37,3.36,3.36,3.36,3.36,3.36,3.37,3.36,3.37,3.39,3.45,3.42,3.39,3.4,3.4,3.39,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.38,3.42,3.42,3.41,3.39,3.39,3.39,3.37,3.38,3.4,3.41,3.44,3.43,3.43,3.43,3.43,3.42,3.42,3.42,3.47,3.46,3.47,3.53,3.65,3.59,3.76,3.85,3.77,3.9,3.76,3.75,3.8,3.73,3.7,3.66,3.68,3.66,3.69,3.68,3.69,3.69,3.61,3.61,3.61,3.59,3.59,3.59,3.63,3.61,3.62,3.63,3.62,3.61,3.61,3.62,3.69,3.66,3.69,3.68,3.66,3.65,3.66,3.68,3.78,3.76,3.77,3.74,3.75,3.77,3.75,3.7,3.7,3.73,3.74,3.79,3.83,3.87,3.86,3.8,3.81,3.78,3.8,3.78,3.78,3.84,3.81,3.81,3.82,3.78,3.75,3.76,3.74,3.72,3.71,3.72,3.78,3.78,3.77,3.76,3.74,3.74,3.75,3.75,3.73,3.72,3.71,3.68,3.7,3.67,3.64,3.56,3.57,3.56,3.61,3.62,3.59,3.57,3.59,3.55,3.54,3.53,3.52,3.53,3.53,3.58,3.6,3.57,3.53,3.53,3.54,3.55,3.57,3.57,3.58,3.64,3.63,3.6,3.6,3.6,3.59,3.6,3.6,3.61,3.61,3.62,3.64,3.64,3.64,3.69,3.73,3.71,3.69,3.69,3.69,3.65,3.66,3.66,3.72,3.73,3.7,3.7,3.72,3.74,3.74,3.74,3.79,3.85,3.9,3.88,3.93,3.86,3.94,4.0,4.0,3.97,3.94,3.93,3.91,3.92,3.94,3.94,3.94,3.99,3.98,4.01,3.99,3.92,3.82,3.71,3.81,3.77,3.76,3.81,3.79,3.83,3.83,3.88,3.89,3.84,3.84,3.83,3.79,3.81,3.8,3.81,3.82,3.83,3.8,3.81,3.81,3.83,3.83,3.86,3.92,3.93,3.97,3.97,3.96,3.95,3.94,3.96,3.98,3.88,3.98,4.0,4.02,4.04,4.08,4.09,4.09,4.16,4.22,4.21,4.19,4.19,4.18,4.19,4.2,4.19,4.2,4.21,4.27,4.3,4.29,4.26,4.29,4.29,4.34,4.36,4.35,4.33,4.33,4.36,4.34,4.33,4.34,4.37,4.35,4.36,4.39,4.38,4.41,4.4,4.4,4.39,4.39,4.41,4.42,4.46,4.48,4.53,4.63,4.65,4.71,4.81,4.91,5.0,4.95,5.04,5.01,4.98,4.9,4.95,4.91,4.8,4.9,4.86,4.76,4.77,4.77,4.79,4.8,4.79,4.81,4.89,4.87,4.87,4.87,4.8,4.79,4.75,4.69,4.69,4.71,4.78,4.76,4.74,4.73,4.8,4.81,4.84,4.83,4.83,4.83,4.79,4.75,4.75,4.66,4.69,4.7,4.68,4.7,4.73,4.72,4.75,4.75,4.75,4.71,4.72,4.71,4.69,4.68,4.64,4.65,4.65,4.66,4.66,4.64,4.65,4.64,4.62,4.63,4.6,4.52,4.45,4.53,4.49,4.5,4.48,4.37,4.39,4.4,4.41,4.43,4.47,4.46,4.45,4.42,4.44,4.45,4.45,4.44,4.43,4.41,4.41,4.44,4.41,4.38,4.38,4.37,4.37,4.38,4.32,4.24,4.29,4.31,4.29,4.27,4.28,4.28,4.28,4.32,4.32,4.33,4.33,4.32,4.33,4.39,4.47,4.47,4.53,4.53,4.53,4.52,4.54,4.51,4.53,4.53,4.53,4.54,4.54,4.58,4.56,4.58,4.56,4.55,4.53,4.54,4.54,4.55,4.54,4.53,4.52,4.49,4.45,4.45,4.46,4.46,4.48,4.46,4.47,4.47,4.49,4.47,4.47,4.48,4.51,4.57,4.57,4.59,4.61,4.57,4.57,4.6,4.64,4.64,4.63,4.65,4.65,4.64,4.64,4.66,4.72,4.73,4.76,4.74,4.8,4.78,4.72,4.76,4.86,4.86,4.88,4.86,4.83,4.85,4.85,4.84,4.81,4.82,4.82,4.82,4.81,4.82,4.85,4.85,4.84,4.82,4.81,4.78,4.81,4.79,4.75,4.78,4.8,4.79,4.78,4.76,4.77,4.77,4.77,4.78,4.79,4.79,4.76,4.75,4.74,4.73,4.74,4.75,4.8,4.81,4.84,4.82,4.8,4.81,4.8,4.77,4.81,4.8,4.81,4.84,4.86,4.83,4.82,4.81,4.8,4.78,4.81,4.81,4.82,4.88,4.84,4.84,4.83,4.83,4.85,4.85,4.83,4.81,4.82,4.79,4.8,4.79,4.78,4.8,4.79,4.78,4.77,4.78,4.77,4.76,]
```

```
from alphashape import alphashape
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from ipywidgets import interact
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook

def alphashape_func(x, y, alpha):
    length = range(len(x))
    # date count
    pnt = [[x[i],y[i]] for i in length]
    # return a shapely.polygon/multipolygon
    alpha_shape = alphashape(pnt, alpha=alpha)
    # convert shapely.polygon/multipolygon to list
    map = mapping(alpha_shape)['coordinates']
    poly_shp = [i[0] for i in map]
    bound_len = len(poly_shp)
    # single alpha shape case
    if bound_len == 1:
        bound_x = [i[0] for i in poly_shp]
        bound_y = [i[1] for i in poly_shp]
    # multiple alpha shape case
    else: 
        bound_x = [[i[0] for i in poly_shp[j]] for j in range(bound_len)]
        bound_y = [[i[1] for i in poly_shp[j]] for j in range(bound_len)]
    # return a dict containing 2 lists: x & y.    
    return {'x':bound_x, 'y':bound_y}
alpha = 5
alpha_high_pnt = alphashape_func(x,y,alpha)
plot = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width', output_backend="webgl")
# line_pnt(plot, max_processed_xy['x'], max_processed_xy['y'],legend_label ='processed_xy',line_color='yellow', line_width=2)
alpha_shape_plt = plot.multi_line(xs=alpha_high_pnt['x'],ys=alpha_high_pnt['y'], line_color='cyan',legend_label = 'alpha_high_pnt')

# create an update function 
def update(alpha=5):
    alpha_high_pnt = alphashape_func(x,y,alpha)
    alpha_shape_plt.data_source.data['xs'] = alpha_high_pnt['x']
    alpha_shape_plt.data_source.data['ys'] = alpha_high_pnt['y']
    # push new values to the notebook
    push_notebook()
output_notebook()
show(plot)
interact(update, alpha=(0,25,1))
```

(the dynamic slider only works when you run it in jupyter in a web browser)

When I drag the slider, it shows an error message:

```
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('xs', 54), ('ys', 99)
```

I don't see the reason of this error, since when I manually adjust the `alpha` value, the lengths of `xs` and `ys` equal.

Can anyone help?

===================== update ======================

Based on @bigreddot suggestion, I update the code to this, the `doesn't match` problem is resolved, but the plot doesn't refresh yet.

```
from alphashape import alphashape
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from ipywidgets import interact

output_notebook()

def alphashape_func(x, y, alpha):
    length = range(len(x))
    # date count
    pnt = [[x[i],y[i]] for i in length]
    # return a shapely.polygon/multipolygon
    alpha_shape = alphashape(pnt, alpha=alpha)
    # convert shapely.polygon/multipolygon to list
    map = mapping(alpha_shape)['coordinates']
    poly_shp = [i[0] for i in map]
    bound_len = len(poly_shp)
    # single alpha shape case
    if bound_len == 1:
        bound_x = [i[0] for i in poly_shp]
        bound_y = [i[1] for i in poly_shp]
    # multiple alpha shape case
    else: 
        bound_x = [[i[0] for i in poly_shp[j]] for j in range(bound_len)]
        bound_y = [[i[1] for i in poly_shp[j]] for j in range(bound_len)]
    # return a dict containing 2 lists: x & y.    
    return {'x':bound_x, 'y':bound_y}

alpha = 5

plot = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width', output_backend="webgl")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=alphashape_func(x,y,alpha))
alpha_shape_plt = plot.multi_line(source=source, xs='x',ys='y', line_color='cyan',legend_label = 'alpha_high_pnt')
print

# create an update function 
def update(alpha=5):
    source.data = alphashape_func(x,y,alpha)
    # push new values to the notebook
    push_notebook()


interact(update, alpha=(0,25,1))

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between this line:

```py
alpha_shape_plt.data_source.data['xs'] = alpha_high_pnt['x']
```

and this line:

```py
alpha_shape_plt.data_source.data['ys'] = alpha_high_pnt['y']
```

the CDS columns are *not* all the same length. If you need to update with data that has a new length you should collect all the updates up front in a `new_data` dict and then set

```py
source.data = new_data
```

to update the CDS "all at once". This is more efficient in any case, as well, since it results in fewer property update change events being sent out.

Comment: I updated the code. the `doesn't match` problem is resolved, but the plot still doesn't refresh. Could you help me further?